# How to use the same variable in 2 Javascript files and modify it

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use the same variable in 2 javascript files modify it in both files and get the updated value to both files.
I tried this. But it doesn't worked.

> first.js

```
let marks = 0;

function func1() {
    function add() {
        marks = marks + 5;
        alert(marks);
        window.location.replace("second.html");
    }
    return {
        add:add;
    }
}

export default func1;
```

> second.js

```
import func1 from '../first';
func1().add();

function func2() {
    function add2() {
        marks = marks + 5;
        alert(marks);
        window.location.replace("third.html");
    }
    return {
        add2:add2;
    }
}

export default func2;
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to have a global variable and change it. Could you please explain what you are trying to achieve? Knowing more about the context we could provide a good answer.

Comment: I want to add 5 marks from the first page if I choose the correct answer. And then redirect to the second question page. If the player choose the correct answer, marks will increase by 5.

Comment: So, as I understand each page is a question, rigth? In this case what you are trying to do will not work, basically each time you redirect to a new page you JS will be reloaded, that means that your variable will be reinitialized every time. The best option would be having a single page, and you should show each question in this page.

Comment: You can also change `marks = marks + 5` to `marks += 5`

Comment: If you are going to new pages, a new process is loaded and your in-memory variables are gone. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986657/persist-variables-between-page-loads

Comment: Store `marks` in localStorage. You can access it on every page, and update it on every page. Warning: you may have to check that it exists on each page before you go about using it or updating it. [MDN LocalStorage Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: Or write a cookie with the current mark value and read it at the next page.

Comment: Thank you very much everyone